# Go to the cell that contains today's date in a Sheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to go to specific cell that contains today's date, but *.getRangeByName()* or *.getA1Notation()* doesn't work. This is my script:

```
item1: function() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var cell = sheet.getRangeByName(date).getA1Notation();
  sheet.setActiveRange(cell);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to select the cells by searching the value of `var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');` in the active sheet using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- Unfortunately, `getRangeByName` cannot be used for searching values. In this case, I would like to propose to use TextFinder.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');

  // I modified below script.
  var ranges = sheet.createTextFinder(date).findAll().map(r => r.getA1Notation());
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).activate();
}
```

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [activate() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#activate())

Comment: Excellent, but it worked for me with '.createTextFinder(date).findNext ();'. Thank you very much for showing me the way.

Comment: I need something like this. Problem is using `en_US` date format it's like this: `"M/d/YYYY"`. So `d` is between `M` and `Y`. I need to filter an entire column with dates and I need to create a block of rows belonging to the same month of the same year. Something like `M/YYY`. But because in en_US `d` is between `M`and `Y` I always get an error: `Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRowGroup.`. I tried: `Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM,yyyy").split(",");`. But it's not working. Any clues? Thx